# make a script in unity compile last

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any way ( preferably in code but the inspector works too) too make a script in unity compile last? I checked with the unity scripting reference and it said to put it in a editor folder, but that would mess with my organization is there any way this is possible?

Comment: have you checked the script compilation reference? http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the inspector and find a script, then click on "Execution Order" at the top

[image]

You will then see the "MonoManager", then you can add scripts by clicking the "+" button and change the order they execute. Otherwise they all execute at the default time in the order they are loaded.

[image: image2]

Comment: Does the above really change *compilation* order or just execution order?

My experiments seem to indicate the latter...